# Save file to temp directory, then call back the url from that temp directory

Tags: ios, swift, download, temporary-files, temporary-directory

I'm using this code for user to download a video to a temporary DIrectory:

```
@IBAction func startDownload(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let videoImageUrl = "http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4"


    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
        let url = NSURL(string: videoImageUrl);
        let urlData = NSData(contentsOf: url! as URL);
        if(urlData != nil)
        {
            let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0];
            let filePath="\(documentsPath)/tempFile.mp4";
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                urlData?.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true);
                PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                    PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath) as URL)
                }) { completed, error in
                    if completed {
                        print("Video is saved!")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, when clicking on the button download, the App get frozen after sometime.

I'd like ideally the file to be save 'temporary' into the App, not to appear int he photolibrary of the Mobile.

How is this possible ?

Then, IS there a way to call back the file from that temporary directory ?

How this can be achieve in the process ?

Thanks a lot guys !

---- EDIT ---

```
 @IBAction func startDownload(_ sender: UIButton) {


        let urlString = "\(posts[selectedIndexPath].link)"

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async(execute: {
            //All stuff here

            print("downloadVideo");
            let url=NSURL(string: urlString);
            let urlData=NSData(contentsOf: url! as URL);

            if((urlData) != nil)
            {
                let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]

                let fileName = urlString as NSString;

                let filePath="\(documentsPath)/\(fileName.lastPathComponent)";

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

                    print(filePath)
                    urlData?.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true);
                    print("video Saved to document directory of app");
                })
            }
        })


}


@IBAction func playDownload(_ sender: UIButton) {


        let urlString = "\(posts[selectedIndexPath].link)"

        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
        let fileName = urlString as NSString;
        let filePath="\(documentsPath)/\(fileName.lastPathComponent)";

        let fileURL = NSURL.init(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
        let request = NSURLRequest.init(url: fileURL as URL)


    print(fireURL)
    print("video called from document directory of app");

        // creating webView to play video, you can use player as per requirement
        let webView = UIWebView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 320))
        webView.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
        self.view.addSubview(webView)



}
```

in the console this is what I get:

```
 /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0A2D4FC0-F001-4711-916C-86C34CC5B71A/Documents/Cabin_Mono_4K_60fps.mp4?alt=media&token=32faeba5-3d9b-4090-9340-3e28986db5fa
video Saved to document directory of app

file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0A2D4FC0-F001-4711-916C-86C34CC5B71A/DocumentsCabin_Mono_4K_60fps.mp4%3Falt=media&token=32faeba5-3d9b-4090-9340-3e28986db5fa
```

Comment: Those are very trivial things to do on iOS. But maybe you should start with an iOS tutorial of some kind because if you ask a question here every step of the way, this is going to take you a very long time.

Comment: Beside, SO is about helping you fix bugs or tackle hard issues, not write code for you.

Comment: Hi Deadbeef, the code does work on save the video into me photolibrary - How can call that file one it is saved ? IF you ahve any pointers, it will be great, I'm not asking for code :)

Comment: Consider to use `downloadTask` of `URLSession`. This is pretty much you are looking for. Loading data synchronously from a remote URL – even dispatched on a background thread – is bad programming habit anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below method will save video to documents directory(specific for app) :

```
func downloadVideo()
{
    let urlString = "http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4"

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async(execute: {
        //All stuff here

        print("downloadVideo");
        let url=NSURL(string: urlString);
        let urlData=NSData(contentsOf: url! as URL);

        if((urlData) != nil)
        {
            let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]

            let fileName = urlString as NSString;

            let filePath="\(documentsPath)/\(fileName.lastPathComponent)";

            let fileExists = FileManager().fileExists(atPath: filePath)

            if(fileExists){

                // File is already downloaded
            }
            else{

                //download
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

                    print(filePath)
                    urlData?.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true);
                    print("videoSaved");
                })
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Wherever you want to get video, you can read it from same document directory as below:

```
    func GetVideo() {

    let urlString = "http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4"

    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
    let fileName = urlString as NSString;
    let filePath="\(documentsPath)/\(fileName.lastPathComponent)";

    let fileURL = NSURL.init(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
    let request = NSURLRequest.init(url: fileURL as URL)


    // creating webView to play video, you can use player as per requirement
    let webView = UIWebView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 320))
    webView.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
    self.view.addSubview(webView)

}
```

Comment: Hi Bhanupriya,

Thanks a lot for your help !

It works perfectly when I call a video by adding the url in the the urlstring such as 'http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4'

however, when I try to call the video dynamically by changing the string to '"\(posts[selectedIndexPath].link)"' it does download the video locally fine - but it doesnt work when I wish to play it . .. 

( see my edited code)

Do you have any advice for that by any chance ? It will be superb !!

Comment: @tibewww print urlString and check if its getting proper url and if it work for you, please upvote and accept answer

Comment: Hi,

Yes the video is being call from the good URL, this is kind of weird, can not figure out why

Comment: print and send me one, let me check

Comment: Thanks Bhanupriya, seems it doesn't call the file from the local, I have edited the question with the updated code calling the print + the Console message if that helps ? Really appreciate your time !

Comment: Ok I jsut edited again the question by printing the fileURL instead, and yes the problem is that its calling : file:///var/ instead of /var/ ! If you have any clue ?

Comment: thats right, that's not an issue. Issue is your video name. What you are saving as "Cabin_Mono_4K_60fps.mp4?alt=media&token=32faeba5-3d9b-4090-9340-3e28986db5fa" something is appending after video name.

Comment: Yep Got iT !

One question about this torage method.

WHen the user quit the App and relaunch it, does the file is going to be deleted ?

If not, is there a way that when the user come back, to recognise that the file has been already downloaded ?

Thanks a lot , thats for information purpose :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136781/discussion-between-bhanupriya-and-tibewww).